# DLL issue with MSpec ReSharper plugin

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resharper, mspec

I am trying to get the MSpec plugin to work with [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) 5.1 running Visual Studio Premium 2010.

I have followed the install procedure and copied the `Machine.Specification.dll` and `Machine.Specifications.ReSharperRunner.5.1.dll` and the associated PDB files to the ReSharper plugins folder.

When Visual Studio starts I get this error message:

[image: Machine.Specification could not be loaded]

How do I resolve this? All the required DLL files are there. The DLL files are not on a network location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open the MSpec DLLs' properties in Explorer and click the "unblock" button on the first tab page. You need to do this for both `Machine.Specifications.dll` and `Machine.Specifications.ReSharperRunner.x.y.dll`.

Comment: With ReSharper 6.1. the message box of the OP doesn't appear and the plugin even shows in the Plugins pane in the options. But it doesn't work. Unblocking it still solved the problem.